# How to embed QFontDialog and QColorDialog into QWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qwidget, qdialog

I need to pop up Qwidget with some properties functions from QMainWindow. This QWidget has to embed QFontDialog and QColorDialog.

I want it pop everything with single click, not via i.e. QFontComboBox... Is it possible? Can these dialogs be embedded into QWidget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `QMdiArea` in your `QMainWindow` and add any dialog as a subwindow. You can make subwindow maximized and frameless if you want.

```
QMdiSubWindow* w = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(new QColorDialog());
w->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
w->showMaximized();
```